# Scala: Get Scala Stream+Process instance from ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala, stream, processbuilder

I have the following options:

Option #1: `lineStream(log: ProcessLogger): Stream[String]` (and 3 similar options)

Option #2: `run(log: ProcessLogger): Process` (and 4 similar options)

**How can I get both, `Stream[String]` + `Process`?**

If that is not possible, how may I early destroy the system process when I decide to use the first option (`Stream[String]` but no `Process` instance)?

[Related API Docs Page (`ProcessBuilder`)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things I don't like about the process API in Scala - you can usually get on or the either, not both. I don't think what you want is possible with the API. If you look at `ProcessBuilderImpl.lineStream()` implementation, the process reference is only stored locally and one doesn't have access to it.

Here's a quick example how you can implement such functionality yourself inspired by how `lineStream()` is actually written under the hood (see `ProcessBuilderImpl` and `BasicIO`). I haven't had the time to polish it (like return something better than a tuple), but it should give you an idea.

```
  object StreamProcessLogger {
    private val nonzeroException = true // set it to whatever suits you

    def run(processBuilder: ProcessBuilder): (Process, Stream[String]) = {
      val logger = new StreamProcessLogger
      val process = processBuilder.run(logger)
      waitForExitInAnotherThread(process, logger)
      (process, logger.stream)
    }

    private def waitForExitInAnotherThread(process: Process, logger: StreamProcessLogger) = {
      val thread = new Thread() {
        override def run() = { logger.setExitCode(process.exitValue()) }
      }
      thread.start()
    }

  }

  private class StreamProcessLogger extends ProcessLogger {
    val queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue[Either[Int, String]]

    override def buffer[T](f: => T): T = f
    override def out(s: => String): Unit = queue.put(Right(s))
    override def err(s: => String): Unit = queue.put(Right(s))

    def stream = next()
    def setExitCode(exitCode: Int) = queue.put(Left(exitCode))

    private def next(): Stream[String] = queue.take match {
      case Left(0) => Stream.empty
      case Left(code) => if (StreamProcessLogger.nonzeroException) scala.sys.error("Nonzero exit code: " + code) else Stream.empty
      case Right(s) => Stream.cons(s, next())
    }
  }
```

And here is the usage:

```
test("returns stream and process") {
  val (process, stream) = StreamProcessLogger.run(Process("ls"))
  stream.foreach(println)
  println(process.exitValue())
}
```